# Css display grid showing with border issue

Tags: html, css

I am using below "display: grid" to align div's, I have not set border to any div. But still it is displaying in mobile view or when we are seeing in small screen. what is the issue, Can we hide these?

I am checking it in chrome browser -- Is there any workaround?

I have added code snippet please check below

[image]

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    background-color: #969596;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="grid-container grid-canvas">
            <div class="row1col1 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row1col2 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row1col3 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row1col4 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row1col5 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row1col6 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row1col7 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row1col8 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="row2col1 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row2col2 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row2col3 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row2col4 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row2col5 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row2col6 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row2col7 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row2col8 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="row3col1 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row3col2 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row3col3 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row3col4 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row3col5 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row3col6 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row3col7 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row3col8 grid-item">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try   `border: none!important;`

Comment: I have tried it but its not working. :(

Comment: check in F12 if `border: none` override please

Comment: Its not related to border color, Background color is applying and displayed. You can check code snippet in mobile view.

Comment: Cannot replicate....either in Codepen or Stack Snippet,

Comment: @Paulie_D please Run code snippet and check full page -- With mobile view. In chrome developer console you can check for mobile view (You might know Just referencing :) )